# file_get_contents takes the php content! and i need the source code in html

Tags: php

I'm trying to take the html content of my .php file with file_get_contents but i can not manage it. It takes .php content no matter what i do so I hope you understand and can help me.

The code for the script:

```
       <?php
            $homepageheader = file_get_contents('xxx/1header.php');
            $homepage2 = file_get_contents('xxx/4.php');
            $homepage3 = file_get_contents('xxx/3.php');
            $homepage4 = file_get_contents('xxx/2.php');
            $homepagefooter = file_get_contents('xxx/5footer.php');                          $spinnercontent = file_get_contents('spinnercontent.php');

    if ($content_type == '1') {

    $linkcontent = "

    $homepageheader


    $homepage2<br>
    $homepage3<br>
    $homepage4<br>
    $homepagefooter
    "; 
    }else{
    $linkcontent = "
            $homepageheader
            $spinnercontent
            $homepagefooter
    ";
```

spinnercontent.php code :

```
<?php
 $first = 'xxx/2.php';
 $second = 'xxxx/3.php';
 $third = 'xxx/4.php';
 $four = 'xxx/5.php';

 $homapagespinner = array($first, $second, $third, $four);
 shuffle($homapagespinner);

 foreach($homapagespinner as $el) {
   include($el);
 }
?>
```

Comment: `file_get_contents` literally gets the file contents. If you want them to be run and get the result, use `include`... *like you already are* inside your `foreach`.

Comment: Yes either `include()` or `file_get_contents('http://host.com/xxx/1header.php');` if allowed.

Comment: not clear what you want to do. "xxx" part should contain http:// if you want to get php output. If you want to include a php source code, use include

Comment: If you want the produced ouput from the php file call them like you will call them in the browser: `file_get_contents('http://example.com/xx/1header.php');` else it will be parsed as txt.

Comment: ... still struggling with the same code you were earlier then..? It would probably help if you ran through a few tutorials to be honest.

Comment: I want to take the html content of spinnercontent.php to include inside my php $tag

Comment: In the example you posted I can't see any $tag and any get_content for spinnercontent.php (I see it now hidden in the right of the page). Please [review](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  your example and format it a bit better.

Comment: .. and creating a PHP file called `spinnercontent.php` won't magically create a variable called `$spinnercontent` that you can drop into a string - which is what it appears you're attempting - it just doesn't work like that. Hitting a few tutorials to grasp the fundamentals will be way quicker than posting on SO - honestly.

Comment: If you want the produced ouput from the php file call them like you will call them in the browser: file_get_contents('http://example.com/xx/1header.php'); else it will be parsed as txt. is the Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the output in a string, you can use the following code:

```
ob_start();
include '/path/to/file.php';
$content = ob_get_clean();
```